# Is this a bug, or did something happen?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Clearly, 10-1+100 is 109, but when I opened this up, it calculated it as 99.

[image]

At the top, it even says:

[image]

So I immediately came here to figure out what was wrong. 100+9 is clearly 109, but the site stated that 100+9 is 99. WHAT IS WRONG???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The entries highlighted in blue, which represent the changes since the last time you checked, correctly sum to +99.